# user with restricted bash: sudo su works but su doesn't

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux, su

I'm creating an user with restricted bash. I've blocked all commands except few commands as per a requirement.

Now if I want to change to root using `su - root`, even with correct password, it says permission denied. There is no logs except in audit log:

With selinux enabled:

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1586888162.535:138142): pid=7433 uid=1022 auid=1022 ses=1432 subj=system_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=? acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=localhost addr=? terminal=pts/2 res=failed'
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1586888164.420:138143): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=5570501b8270 a1=1 a2=1d09 a3=5e95fde4 items=1 ppid=6219 pid=7433 auid=1022 uid=1022 gid=1021 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=1021 sgid=1021 fsgid=1021 tty=pts2 ses=1432 comm="su" exe="/usr/bin/su" subj=system_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 key="session"
```

With selinux disabled:

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1586892761.375:2598): pid=22286 uid=1022 auid=1022 ses=11 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=? acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=localhost addr=? terminal=pts/1 res=failed'
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1586892763.583:2599): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=55ab87b90270 a1=1 a2=570e a3=5e960fdb items=1 ppid=14412 pid=22286 auid=1022 uid=1022 gid=1021 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=1021 sgid=1021 fsgid=1021 tty=pts1 ses=11 comm="su" exe="/usr/bin/su" key="session"
```

I tried to enable su logging from login.defs, also enabled su logging redirecting to syslog. But nothing seems to work. I'm not able to find why `su` is failing. My current guess it's a restricted bash and may be it's unable to change the bash while doing su. Just a guess.

So for trying another approach I added an entry for the above in sudoers file and `sudo su -` works fine. But it takes the current user's password and not the target user's password. Which will be another issue.

So help is needed with either enabling su logging or su login from restricted bash or ask target user's password while doing `sudo su`.

Note:

1. The OS is RHEL 7.
2. selinux is currently disabled.

Comment: Do you have a `unix_chkpwd` binary and is it setuid?

Comment: Yes I've and it's with suid. -rwsr-xr-x. But for the user with restricted bash, this is not allowed.

Comment: How did you implement the restriction? (I mean, _normally_ "restricted bash" only affects user input and cannot affect other programs directly starting another executable, but I have to ask anyway)

Comment: I've changed the path to its home directory only and created soft links of 2 binaries which are allowed for this user. So since it's rbash, it can't change its path and can't execute anything other than those 2 binaries pointed by the soft link.